# Magento 2: What is the difference between plugins and modules?

Tags: magento2

Some modules are called plugins and majority of the modules I found are called modules. I'm new to Magento 2 and this seems confuses me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In magento2,

Plugin and Module are different.

If you have working on WordPress then, to your point **view Magento module is called as Plugin**. In Language of ***WordPress Plugin = Magento module***

At magento Plugin is different,

> A plugin, or interceptor, is a class that modifies the behavior of
>   public class functions by intercepting a function call and running
>   code before, after, or around that function call. This allows you to
>   substitute or extend the behavior of original, public methods for any
>   class or interface

.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: You  are  welcome

Answer (score 0):

In just one line as per Magento:

> plugin is a class to play with one or more function with out modify function body.

You can add your code before/after/around to that function.

> While module is an extension that is a kind of package with features and functionality.

And a module can have one or more plugin class inside in Magento.